# Meta-analysis of Kaplan-Meier survival estimates from one-arm studies

Tags: mixed-model, survival, meta-analysis, glmm, kaplan-meier

I am writing this topic because there is a statistical problem which does not let me sleep at night.

For introduction, I am a clinical researcher interested in niche fields, and many of my projects deal with (very) low-quality evidence. In fact, often times we are talking about exclusively single-arm studies, which provide only Kaplan-Meier survival estimates. Since I focus on clinical aspects, and my knowledge in statistics is limited, most of the time I am working with a trained Statistician; however, I am very keen on understanding the concept better.

**Problem:**
Assume that we have ten studies describing a new method of treatment in oncology. All ten studies are single-arm trials, which provide Kaplan-Meier survival estimation curve as the only outcome. We are interested in performing a meta-analysis (MA) to estimate a pooled outcome, and we assume that 5-year survival probability would be appropriate. We extract the 5-year survival probability (SP) for each study, along with a corresponding standard error (SE), through digitizing the curve and reconstructing IPD.

**Solution one**
Just assume that probabilities are proportions, round events to nearest whole numbers, and use 0.5 continuity correction for studies with 0 or 1 probability. In this case, I would use arcsine transformation, and appropriate adjustments (e.g. maximum likelihood, K-H adjustment), and just calculate with Random Effects Model (REM).

This, however, ignores that probabilities =/= proportions. Moreover, if I understand correctly, the unbalanced continuity adjustment becomes a noticeable input towards the MA average, especially for low denominators (e.g. n=10).

**Solution two**
Use logit transformation of the SP with corresponding SE and calculate inverse-variance REM MA. However, I can't think of a good way to deal with 0 or 1 probabilities, as they produce corresponding SE of 0, an invalid input for inverse-variance MA.

Arbitrary adjustment of small SE seems bad, since it overestimates study weight.

**Solution three**
Use the logit-transformed probabilities as input for generalised linear mixed model to deal with 0-event (or full-event) studies. It also seems preferable for studies with low number of cases.

However, I still think that there is room to improve. Did any of you have previous experiences with such analyses, and if yes, what method would you choose to calculate the MA average?

Please let me know if it is one of the methods mentioned above, or perhaps another approach.

I understand that for relatively low-quality studies, study-level heterogeneity likely outweighs the differences in MA averages between approaches, but still. The subject of one-arm study MA recurs for me often, and I want to improve, if possible.

Thank you for your input!